# Installation failed with message null - Genymotion Error

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, genymotion

I am new to Android Programming and I am still learning the basis. I have installed the Android Studio and Genymotion as mentioned in the tutorials provided. When I run my Android app using the bundled Emulator everything is working fine. But, with Genymotion, I encountered the following error :

> **Installation failed with message null. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it
>   is present, and then re-installing.**

Following are the versions of the software I am using...

- Android Studio 1.4
- Java 8
- Oracle VirtualBox Version 5.0.6 r103037
- Genymotion Version 2.5.2 Revision 20150717-d5a1e88

And if it would help I am using a Linux system with Ubuntu 14.04 disto. I have attached the sequential screen shots regarding how the error is encountered. Thanks a lot.

[image: Genymotion Emulator is visible in devices] [image: Genymotion Emulator Starts] [image: The Error] [image: Log Status after error]