# on Click NoteEditFragment.java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
error at com.example.root.notebook.NoteEditFragment$4.onClick(NoteEditFragment.java:146)
```

And line number 146 is below

```
 Log.d("Save Note", "Note title: " + title.getText() + "Note message: " + message.getText() + "Note Category: " + savedButtonCategory);
```

Below is my code

```
    package com.example.root.notebook;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.zip.Inflater;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class NoteEditFragment extends Fragment {

        private ImageButton noteCatButton;
        private Note.Category savedButtonCategory;
        private AlertDialog categoryDialogObject,confirmDialogObject;
        private EditText title,message;
        private static final String MODIFIED_CATEGORY="Modified Category";

        private boolean newNote=false;
        private long noteId= 0;

        public NoteEditFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
            if (bundle!=null){

                newNote=bundle.getBoolean(NoteDetailActivity.NEW_NOTE_EXTRA,false);
            }

            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                savedButtonCategory=(Note.Category) savedInstanceState.get(MODIFIED_CATEGORY);

            }

            View fragmentLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_edit, container, false);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            EditText title=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteTitle);
            EditText message=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteMessage);
            ImageButton noteCatButton=(ImageButton) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteButton);
            Button savedButton=(Button) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.saveNote);


            Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();

            title.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_EXTRA));
            message.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTRA));
            noteId=intent.getExtras().getLong(MainActivity.NOTE_ID_EXTRA,0);


            if (savedButtonCategory!=null)
            {
                noteCatButton.setImageResource(Note.categoryToDrawable(savedButtonCategory));
            }
            else if(!newNote) {
                Note.Category noteCat = (Note.Category) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA);
                savedButtonCategory = noteCat;
                noteCatButton.setImageResource(Note.categoryToDrawable(noteCat));
            }
            buildCategoryDialog();
            buildConfirmDialog();
            noteCatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    categoryDialogObject.show();
                }
            });
            savedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    confirmDialogObject.show();
                }
                });
                return fragmentLayout;
            }

        @Override
         public  void  onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            savedInstanceState.putSerializable(MODIFIED_CATEGORY,savedButtonCategory);
        }

        private void  buildCategoryDialog(){

            final String[] categories=new String[]{"Personal","Technical","Quote","Finance"};
            AlertDialog.Builder categoryBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            categoryBuilder.setTitle("Choose Note Type");
            categoryBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(categories, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    categoryDialogObject.cancel();
                    switch (item) {
                        case 0:

                            savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.PERSONAL;
                            noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.p);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.TECHNICAL;
                            noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.t);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.QUOTE;
                            noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.q);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            savedButtonCategory = Note.Category.FINANCE;
                            noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.f);
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            categoryDialogObject=categoryBuilder.create();

        }

      private void buildConfirmDialog(){
          AlertDialog.Builder confirmBuilder =new  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
          confirmBuilder.setTitle("Are you sure?");
          confirmBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure to save? ");
          confirmBuilder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  Log.d("Save Note", "Note title: " + title.getText() + "Note message: " + message.getText() + "Note Category: " + savedButtonCategory);

                  NotebookDbAdapter dbAdapter = new NotebookDbAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());

                  dbAdapter.open();
                  if (newNote) {
                      dbAdapter.createNote(title.getText() + "", message.getText() + "", (savedButtonCategory == null) ? Note.Category.PERSONAL : savedButtonCategory);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      dbAdapter.updateNote(noteId, title.getText() + "", message.getText() + "", savedButtonCategory);
                  }
                  dbAdapter.close();
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
          });
           confirmBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               }
           });
          confirmDialogObject=confirmBuilder.create();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, what is the expected behaviour, and what is your concrete issue. Just looking through >150 lines of uncommented/undocumented code is not really easy. People are willing to help you if you provide a [*minimal*, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok i post here locgcate

Comment: notebook app not insertion occure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new EditText instance in your onCreate() method, so your global instances are always null.

Modify this lines

```
EditText title=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteTitle);
EditText message=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteMessage);
ImageButton noteCatButton=(ImageButton) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteButton);
```

to this:

```
title=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteTitle);
message=(EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteMessage);
noteCatButton=(ImageButton) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteButton);
```

in your onCreate() method.

Comment: thanks @Suhyeon Lee  please 2 min see here for further query can i ask you

Comment: @programmingschool I will answer you as far as I know, that's not a problem.

Comment: now error :   installation failed with message null

Comment: error : it is possible to issue is resolved by uninstalling existing version ?

Comment: I'm not a wizard from Hogwart and I cannot help that kind of question. You should ask with detail.

Comment: as i did changes my code , changing not applied , compiling error ,uninstall   current app with data

Comment: this error ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315753/installation-failed-with-message-null-genymotion-error

Comment: @programmingschool Then uninstall your app manually first and reinstall the new one.

Comment: I mean remove your App in your device by your finger, not a command or programming.